# OCR for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ocr

Has anyone got experience in using an OCR toolkit that can be used from Silverlight?

If so, does the Silverlight app need to use elevated privileges?

Did it work on the Mac, Windows Phone as well as a PC?  (The PC case is most important for me)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [LEADTOOLS](http://www.leadtools.com/default.htm) SDK before in my SL3 application. I believe they have OCR for .NET as well, but not sure if that includes Silvelight. You may want to check them out.

Comment: The last time I looked leadtools had high runtime costs if you wished to ship a app using them.   Has this changed?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: If you are referring to the licensing costs then probably not. Our client was also unhappy with how it was structured.

Answer (score 0):

OCR-IT OCR Cloud 2.0 is OS-independent web-based cloud OCR service.  I worked with Silverlight developers who successfully implemented it.  For .NET there is complete sample code provided.  You can contact the company should you require additional support or assistance.  There is also no issue with high-cost licensing as it is free to start and simple pay-per-use once you go into production.  Check the website for latest licensing details: http://www.ocr-it.com/ocr-cloud-2-0-api